# Open Passive FTP (Socket) connection using Python

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

I am trying to connect to an FTP server in Passive mode from Python (through Socket)

i am doing it this way:

```
mftp = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
mftp.connect((serverHost, 21))
print mftp.recv(1024)
print mftp.close()
```

but this command (.connect) i believe opens an active connection to the server. How can i open a passive connection. Please help, and also while responding, also consider i am very new to Python ... :)

Regards,
M.Ali

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question... but did you know Python has an [FTP module](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) as part of its standard library?  It might be suitable for your needs, and could save you a lot of time.

Comment: yeh but due to some restrictions, i can use that, i need to do that through Sockets ...